# Split a tab into two-lightning app builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, app-builder

I am building a lightning app builder page. this page has tabs component. One of the tabs is collaboration which will have activities and chatter fields component. These two components were placed one after other. Is there a way to split the tab into 2 and show them side by side?

Comment: I think one solution could be - to put the component twice - one in each tab, and have set the  `Set Component Visibility` of the component for each one to show and hide according to what you want

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can't split two components in builder page. Use can use one wrapper component to split two components side by side.